# Open XML: Convert a Paragraph to simple HTML

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a Paragraph object and wish to convert the inner text it contains into HTML fragments.

I use the Open XML SDK 2.0 from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [Test]
    public void GetHTMLOutOfParagraphsWithoutHeadingInformation()
    {

        var paragraphs = new List<Paragraph>();
        StyleDefinitionsPart styles = null;

        // Open the file read-only since we don't need to change it.
        using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentFileName, true))
        {
            paragraphs = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
                .OfType<Paragraph>().ToList();
            styles = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;

            foreach (var p in paragraphs)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(memoryStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                    doc.AddMainDocumentPart().AddPart(styles);
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body();
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(p.CloneNode(true));
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                    Console.WriteLine(GetHTMLOfDoc(doc));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    string GetHTMLOfDoc(WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {

        HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
        {
            PageTitle = "Test Title",
            CssClassPrefix = "Pt",
            Css = "",
            ConvertFormatting = false,

        };

        XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings);
        var notNullAnyMore = html.XPathSelectElement("//*[local-name() = 'body']");
        return notNullAnyMore.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to need these namespaces for the above code:
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.IO;